# What is the end result of this machine learning tutorial?

Tags: tensorflow

I've been trying to learn tensorflow and machine learning and this article was one of the first tutorials I've stumbled onto: https://medium.com/towards-data-science/tensorflow-for-absolute-beginners-28c1544fb0d6. I stepped through the code and thought I understood the vast majority of it but then I got to the final output which was a set of 3 numbers, the weights. How are these weights supposed to be used? That is, how would I put this result to use in a real world scenario?

Comment: Weights will not be used. In the last step the person is just printing the weights. The import step is "mse". with each epoch the mse will fall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weights are what you are trying to optimize.

The goal is to find a set of weights, that when given a set of inputs will ouput the right answer.

In this case, you have 1 (True) and -1 (False) inputs and a bias that is always one. The goal is to learn the AND function. The function should return 1 (True) only when both inputs are 1 (True), -1 (False) otherwise.

When given a new input [1, -1, 1] (bias is always one in this case), the function will multiply these inputs by the weights you computed earlier and sum the result. If the result of this is greater than 0 it will output 1, if not, it will ouput -1